# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401 while trying to get list items from sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, jquery, ajax

We are trying to deploy a `SAP UI5` (JS framework) based application (Contains HTML, JS and CSS files like regular web application) on one of the IIS servers in customer landscape.

This app to fetch a list information from one of the share point backend systems by using ajax GET request.But we are always ending up with

```
'Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401' Error.
```

Please help us here.

Answer (score 1):

for some one coming here and not finding the answer, under custom header of http protocol

add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS"/>
add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />

Answer (score 0):

401 error is related to access issue. Make sure the account has valid permission to read the SharePoint library. and the same account has access to your preflight thing.